# Renaming a contact group on Android

Tags: htc-desire, contacts

Is there any way to rename a contact group on the HTC Desire?

Via "Edit Group" in People you can add and remove members, but the title doesn't seem to be editable.

I could add a new group of course and move contacts over, but unless there's an easy way to do this en-mass this would be inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Go to www.google.com and sign in. Click settings in the top right corner. Then click on "Dashboard      View data stored with this account". This will take you to your dashboard. Scroll down and you can manage contacts. The only group names you can edit are the ones you created yourself. The default Google ones are not editable.

Comment: Ah, this works though as it happens it looks like the group I was trying to edit is a default one, and thus isn't editable.  Normal user - created groups are actually rename-able on the phone, I was just confused.

Comment: Thats good to know that it is also editable on the phone.